# Laravel Eloquent / SQL - search for keywords in db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently trying to implement a search for keywords/tags in my db.

In my db, I have lines with keywords like:
`auto,cabrio,frischluft` or
`hose,jeans,blaue hose,kleidung`

so always some keywords (that can basically also have a whitespace), seperated by a comma (`,`).

Now I want to be able to find a product in my db that has some keywords entered.

With `LIKE` I can find the two entries I mentioned with queries like `auto,cabrio` or also `cabrio,frischluft` or `hose,jeans,blau` or `hose,kleidung`. But what happens if I enter `auto,frischluft` or something like `hose,blaue hose` or `jeans,kleidung`?

Then `LIKE` wont work any more. Is there a way to do this?

I hope you know what I mean...

So just to make it clear: The code I currently use is:
`$searchQuery = "%".$request->input('productSearch')."%";`

and                 `$products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', $searchQuery)->paginate(15);`

But as I said, this won't bring me back the article with the keyowrds `auto,cabrio,frischluft` if the input `productSearch` has the keywords `auto,frischluft` entered...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I know I'm late for the party but this is the first result in Google when I was looking for Eloquent keywords search. I had the same problem and I want to help with my solution.

```
$q = $request->input('productSearch');
$needles = explode(',', $q);

// In my case, I wanted to split the string when a comma or a whitespace is found:
// $needles = preg_split('/[\s,]+/', $q);

$products = Products::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$q}%");

foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    $products = $products->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$needle}%");
}

$products = $products->paginate(15);
```

If the user input has too many commas, the `$needles` array could be too large (and the query too huge), so you can limit the search, for example, for only the first 5 elements in the array:

```
$needles = array_slice($needles, 0, 5);
```

I hope this can help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

On your reply just now:

If you want it simpler, read this MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html.

Basically, in a file you could `grep` for `[,]?blaue hose[,]?` to find: an optional comma, the string 'blaue hose', and an optional comma.

The more solid solution would be my initial answer:

You could actually create a keyword table, depending on your `products` table, where each keyphrase/keyword 
is in one column by itself, and even lay an index on the keyphrase/keyword. I explain the principle here:

[Optimising LIKE expressions that start with wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879054/optimising-like-expressions-that-start-with-wildcards/41879903#41879903)

And, to take your example as input - here is how I do that in Vertica. Many databases offer a function that returns
the n-th part/token of a string delimited by a character of your choice. In Vertica, it's SPLIT_PART().

MySQL, unfortunately, does not offer any correspondence to that function, and you would have to convert the Common Table Expressions in the WITH clauses below to in-line SELECT-s (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... ) AS foo(col1,col2,col3) ....`. And then, there is a suggestion here From Daniel Vassallo on how to tackle it:

[Split value from one field to two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696884/split-value-from-one-field-to-two)

In Vertica, it would look like this:

```
WITH 
-- input
products(prod_id,keywords) AS (
          SELECT 1001,'auto,cabrio,frischluft'
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'hose,jeans,blaue hose,kleidung'
)
,
-- index to get the n-th part of the comma delimited string
max_keyword_count(idx) AS (
          SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3
UNION ALL SELECT 4
UNION ALL SELECT 5
)
SELECT
  prod_id
, idx
, TRIM(SPLIT_PART(keywords,',',idx)) AS keywords
FROM products
CROSS JOIN max_keyword_count
WHERE SPLIT_PART(keywords,',',idx) <> ''
ORDER BY
  prod_id
, idx
;

prod_id|idx|keywords
  1,001|  1|auto
  1,001|  2|cabrio
  1,001|  3|frischluft
  1,002|  1|hose
  1,002|  2|jeans
  1,002|  3|blaue hose
  1,002|  4|kleidung
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but this sounds very difficult.. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: In that case, read this MySQL documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html . Basically, in a file you could `grep` for `[,]?blaue hose[,]?` to find: an optional comma, the string  'blaue hose', and an optional comma.

Comment: but this is basically what `LIKE` would do, too, isn't it? Because how could I use your idea when using `hose,blaue hose`? Should end in the product with the keywords `hose,jeans,blaue hose,kleidung`

Comment: If what you mean is that you give a list of keywords as input, and hope to find a match if you search for 'hose, blaue hose'  in 'hose,jacke,jeans,blaue hose' - then this is not a SQL question you could ask. You would have to programmatically convert the search condition to `WHERE keywords LIKE '%hose% OR keywords LIKE '%blaue hose%'`.

Comment: okay, you might be right, but if I use an OR like you suggested now, I would run in the issue, that there would also be results that only contain `hose` or `blaue hose`, but not both together. But I think you got my idea. I have a product with a list of keywords, then I want to be able to pass a list of keywords to a search field and I want to find products that contain all keywords, passed from the search box, no matter in which order they are saved for the product

Comment: And in that case, I would go through the vertical splitting as explained in my answer, at least if it is a big table, to have the chance of dramatically speeding up the search. There, you could actually put an `IN('hose','blaue hose')` into the WHERE condition and use an index

Comment: Then, AND istead of OR

Comment: I'll try that idea, propably won't be too easy, because I don't know how many keywords are passed so I need to split the `keywords` string on the comma and need to add a `AND ...` for every keyword in the array (that contains the spliited string)